# QlikSense: Incomplete visualizations

Tags: qliksense

I'm hoping to get an explanation of why this behaves this way. I've recently implemented a variable and it works brilliantly, but I've just discovered that upon initial opening of the report, it shows incomplete visualizations. Strangely, as soon as I change the the option in my parameter, it switches back to normal operation, even if I go back to the parameter option that it was initially sitting on.

Upon opening report:

[image]

And as soon as I change the option (from PDT to CDT, for example) the data populates. It remains populated, and correctly changes if I go back to PDT even:

[image]

So to get specific, this parameter changes the StartDate and EndDate timestamps in the results above. This is the expression behind the StartDate:

```
=if(Month(Today())=Month(Pick($(TimeZone), Start_PDT, Start_MDT, Start_CDT, Start_EDT)), Date(Pick($(TimeZone), Start_PDT, Start_MDT, Start_CDT, Start_EDT), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.fff] TT'))
```

And the EndDate:

```
=Date(Pick($(TimeZone), End_PDT, End_MDT, End_CDT, End_EDT), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.fff] TT')
```

EDIT: Here is an example of the error seen for the StartDate column. Of course, this error disappears once you start changing the parameter option:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure your variable has a preset definition, which you can set in the [Variables dialog box](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Sheets/variables-dialog.htm):

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense variables dialog box]

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you!